# how to use useRef for the attribute htmlFor?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to customize the input tag for file upload.
This is my code. Here for the attribute htmlFor, I am giving id of the input tag.Then it is working. But instead I want to use useRef ref. How can I do that ? If I follow the below method, it will be problematic if I render this component more than once. right ?

```
const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        accept=".pdf"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        id="raised-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
        onChange={e => {
          setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
      <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
        <button component="span">
          <span>file</span>
        </button>
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way of using `<label>` tag is by wrapping your element as a child without specifying an `id` for it.

```
<label>
  <input
    accept=".pdf"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    multiple
    type="file"
    onChange={e => {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }}
  />
  <span>File</span>
</label>
```

If you prefer to open your file input dialog with your ref, you can do like this.

```
const handleOpenFileInput = () => {
  inputRef.current.click();
};
```

```
<label onClick={handleOpenFileInput}>
  <button>file</button>
</label>
<input
  ref={inputRef}
  accept=".pdf"
  style={{ display: "none" }}
  multiple
  type="file"
  onChange={e => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `userRef` it won't solve your problem. The problem is in the `label` and the `htmlFor` attribute. It constantly gets the inputs whose ids match the `htmlFor` attribute, and since your render the component multiple times, it always gets the first match.

I would simply pass the `id` of each component as a property, so that each time the label matches the right input. I would change the code to look more like this:

```
const Form = ({id}) => {
  const onChangeInput = e => {
    const [file] = e.target.files
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <input type="file" id={id} name="file" className="my-input" accept="application/pdf" style={{display:"none"}} onChange={onChangeInput} multiple/>
        <label htmlFor={id}>Upload</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form id="form1"/>
      <Form id="form2"/>
      <Form id="form3"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To make sure that each document has been uploaded correctly, I passed a `className` attribute to the inputs so I can get all of them. Running this code, I find all files that I have uploaded

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.my-input')).map(v => v.files[0].name)
```